# Weird dictionary ContainsKey issue

Tags: c#

Before I start, I'd like to clarify that this is not like all the other somewhat "similar" questions out there. I've tried implementing each approach, but the phenomena I am getting here are really weird.

I have a dictionary where `ContainsKey` always returns `false`, even if their `GetHashCode` functions return the same output, and even if their `Equals` method returns `true`.

What could this mean? What am I doing wrong here?

**Additional information**

The two elements I am inserting are both of type `Owner`, with no `GetHashCode` or `Equals` method. These inherit from a type `Storable`, which then implements an interface, and also has `GetHashCode` and `Equals` defined.

Here's my `Storable` class. You are probably wondering if the two `Guid` properties are indeed equal - and yes, they are. I double-checked. See the sample code afterwards.

```
public abstract class Storable : IStorable
{

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Id == default(Guid) ? 0 : Id.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as Storable;
        return other != null && (other.Id == Id || ReferenceEquals(obj, this));
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    protected Storable()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

}
```

Now, here's the relevant part of my code where the dictionary stuff occurs. It takes in a `Supporter` object which has a link to an `Owner`.

```
public class ChatSession : Storable, IChatSession
{

    static ChatSession()
    {
        PendingSupportSessions = new Dictionary<IOwner, LinkedList<IChatSession>>();
    }

    private static readonly IDictionary<IOwner, LinkedList<IChatSession>> PendingSupportSessions;

    public static ChatSession AssignSupporterForNextPendingSession(ISupporter supporter)
    {

        var owner = supporter.Owner;
        if (!PendingSupportSessions.ContainsKey(owner)) //always returns false
        {
            var hashCode1 = owner.GetHashCode();
            var hashCode2 = PendingSupportSessions.First().Key.GetHashCode();

            var equals = owner.Equals(PendingSupportSessions.First().Key);

            //here, equals is true, and the two hashcodes are identical,
            //and there is only one element in the dictionary according to the debugger.
            //however, calling two "Add" calls after eachother does indeed crash.

            PendingSupportSessions.Add(owner, new LinkedList<IChatSession>());
            PendingSupportSessions.Add(owner, new LinkedList<IChatSession>()); //crash
        }

        ...

    }

}
```

*If you need additional information, let me know. I am not sure what kind of information would be sufficient, so it was hard for me to include more.*

Comment: _"I have a dictionary where ContainsKey always returns null"_ [`ContainsKey `](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `bool` not an object.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code?

Comment: @TimSchmelter sorry about that. I corrected the issue.

Comment: Can you let us know what was the issue

Comment: You should not change the value of your keys once they are added to the dictionary. That may be the issue. Preffer imutable types for keys. (Provide sample code)

Comment: @MariusBancila I just provided more code and details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guillaume was right. It appears that I was changing the value of one of my keys after it is added to the dictionary. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are passing same object that is stored as key in dictionary. If you are creating new object each time and trying to find key assuming the object is already stored because of similar values, then containsKey returns false. Object comparisons are different than value comparisons.